# python: algorithm - to gather items from mean

Tags: python, algorithm

Not sure whether this is the right place, but I have a question related to algorithm and I cant think of an efficient algorithm.
So thought of sharing my problem statement.. :)
To ease up what I am trying to explain, let me create a hypothetical example.

Suppose, I have a list which contains an object whcih contains two things..

```
lets say product id and price
```

Now, this is a long long list..sort of like an inventory.. 
out of this I have defined three price segments.. lowprice, midprice and highprice
and then k1,k2,k3 where k1,k2 and k3 are ratios.
So, the job is now,, I have to gather products from this huge inventory in such a way that there is n1 products from lowprice range, n2 products from midprice range and n3 products from high price range... where n1:n2:n3 == k1:k2:k3

Now, how do I efficiently achieve the following.
I target the low price point is 100 dollars
and I have to gather 20 products from this range..
mid price range is probably 500 dollars
and so on

So I start with 100 dollars.. and then look for items between 90 and 100 and also between 100 and 110
Let say I found 5 products in interval 1 low (90,100) and 2 products in interval 1 high (100,110)
Then, I go to next low interval and next high interval.
I keep on doing this until I get the number of products in this interval.

How do I do this?? Also there might be case, when the number of products in a particular price range is less than what I need.. (maybe mid price range is 105 dollars...).. so what should I do in that case..
Please pardon me, if this is not the right platform.. as from the question you can make out that this is more like a debative question rather than the "I am getting this error" type of question.
Thanks

Comment: Would it be easier if you sort the items N, then based on the ratios, divive the N into n1:n2:n3 respectively?

Comment: @AlvinK. Hmm.. that could be one solution though I wont be able to really use some of the stats I have calculated.. But definitely a very awesome example of how a lil bit of assumption can lead to easy programming.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

First find the `n1`'th smallest element, let it be `e1`, and the **lower bound list** is all elements such that `element <= e1`.

Do the same for the other ranges.

pseudo code for lower bound list:

```
getLowerRange(list,n):
  e <- select(list,n) 
  result <- []
  for each element in list:
     if element <= e:
         result.append(element)
  return result
```

**Note** that this solution fails if there are many "identical" items [result will be a bigger list], but finding those items, and removing it from result list is not hard.

Note that selection algorithm is `O(n)`, so this algorithm will consume linear time related to your list's size.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1**

If the assignment what products belong to the three price segments never changes, why don't you simply build 3 lists, one for the products in each price segment (assuming these sets are disjoint).
Then you may pick from these lists randomly ([either with or without replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29#Replacement_of_selected_units) - as you like). The number of items for each class is given by the ratios.

**Approach 2**

If the product-price-segment assignment is intended to be pre-specified, e.g., by passing corresponding price values for each segment on function call, you may want to have the products sorted by price and use a binary search to select the [m-nearest-neighbors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) (for example). The parameter `m` could be specified according to the ratios. If you specify a maximum distance you may reject products that are outside the desired price range.

**Approach 3**

If the product-price-segment assignment needs to be determined autonomously, you could apply your [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) algorithm of choice, e.g., [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means), to assign your products to, say, `k = 3` price segments. For the actual product selection you may proceed similarly as described above.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you should try a database solution rather then using a list. Check out sqlite. It's in Python by default